# Common zeroes of multivariable p-adic polynomials

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am reading Serre's *A Course in Arithmetic*, and I have some doubts about a proposition regarding the set of common zeroes of polynomials with $p$-adic coefficients. In the following, note that $\mathbf Z_p$ denotes the $p$-adic integers (not $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$), and $A_n$ denotes $\mathbf Z/p^n\mathbf Z$. (Hence, $\mathbf Z_p=\varprojlim A_n$.) The following is the relevant excerpt from the text.

[image]

I think I understand most of this, except in the statement of proposition 5 under (ii), why is it that we require $n>1$ instead of $n\geq 1$? I don't seem to understand where the proof requires the fact that $n\neq 1$. Is this a typo or am I missing something obvious? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I can guess, ii) with $n > 1$ and ii) with $n \geq 1$ are easily seen to be equivalent – so I’m not sure why Serre chose this wording. Maybe there’s a reason later.

Comment: @Mindlack thanks! I actually didn't even realise they were equivalent, that was helpful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to get this off the unanswered list...

As mentioned by Mindlack in the comments, the two versions of (ii) with $n\geq 1$ or $n>1$ are equivalent. One sees this by noting that a zero of a polynomial mod $p^2$ also gives a zero mod $p$ for obvious reasons. In the later pages, Serre also states similar results with $n>1$, and they are also equivalent to the $n\geq 1$ case for the same reason.